# Classes derived from TreeViewItem don't work in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

My interface:

```
public interface IWorkAreaTreeViewItem
{
    string Text { get; }
    int? Status { get; }
    ObservableCollection<IWorkAreaTreeViewItem> Children { get; }
    IEntityViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}
```

My xaml

```
    <TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource treeViewItemsViewSource}}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:IWorkAreaTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=treeView}" Stretch="Fill" >
                        <Image.Source>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource statusToImageSourceConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Status" />
                                <Binding Path="ViewModel"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>            
    </TreeView>
```

When i derive my implementation of `IWorkAreaTreeViewItem`  from `TreeViewItem` the structure in my `TreeView` is ok, but the items only show the Content of `TreeViewItem.Header`.

When i don't derive from `TreeViewItem` it's all fine. Each item is shown with image and text.

Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Your *data item* class should not be derived from the *item container* class (i.e. TreeViewItem). The item container is created internally and used to host/contain/visualize your data item. Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: I thought, the type of ItemCollecion in a WPF-TreeView is abitrary and using a derivation from TreeViewItem, offers the whole functionality of TreeViewItem to my dataitem. When i take an item from  TreeViews-ItemCollection it is neither a TreeViewItem :-(

Comment: The *item* is meant to be a representation of your data, while the *item container*, well, contains (i.e. visualizes) the item. Your data item should be modeled in a way that is independent of the visualization, hence it should not be a TreeViewItem.